# MKMapView sometimes not de-clustering

Tags: swift, mkmapview

On a project I have implemented clustering of pins in a map. After tapping a cluster annotation of two very close pins (not equal locations) in most trials it correctly de-clusters and shows the two underlying annotations. But in one out of ten trials (approximately) it does not and it behaves as if the two pins were equal --- the cluster annotation only enlarges to demonstrate that it is selected.

for showing underlying annotations when tapping the cluster I am using

```swift
mapView.showAnnotations(annotation.memberAnnotations, animated: true)
```

What could cause this behaviour? I could not find anywhere how the clustering actually works inside to detect the cause of this issue. Did anyone experience the same issue?

Comment: i had that one long ago. it's because on while i try to zoom map so many times it will de cluster locations pin.

Comment: @jatinfl I am sorry I don't really understand what you are referring to. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I have same problem. when more then two pins have same coordinate or almost same coordinate then cluster pin is not spread out. how to handle this scenario in the tableview anyone knows?